# How to prevent JBoss EAP 6.4.X from resolving expression in property value?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, java.util.logging, jboss-logging

I have Jboss server (EAP 6.4.X) working in domain mode.

In domain.xml I have custom-handler defined. Class specified in custom-handler definition is enclosed in Jboss module.

The definition is as follows:

```
<custom-handler name="SomeCustomHandlerName" class="com.abc.def.SomeCustomHandler" module="com.abc.def">
   <level name="ALL"/>
   <properties>
      ...
      <property name="somePropertyKey" value="${some.property.value}"/>
      ...
   </properties>
</custom-handler>
```

When I start the Jboss I get this error:

```
2018-12-04 18:33:30,564 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("custom-handler" => "SomeCustomHandlerName")
]) - failure description: "JBAS014802: Cannot resolve expression '${some.property.value}'"
```

As I see Jboss tries to resolve `${some.property.value}` expression using system-properties. However this value should be resolved internally by `com.abc.def.SomeCustomHandler` class.

The question is how to tell Jboss not to interpret this value and pass it as raw property value to `SomeCustomHandler` class? Maybe there is a simple way to escape `${}` like `\$\{\}` or something like that?

Comment: Did you solve somehow? Same error on 7.2 when executing:  
`/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=JDBC_PING/property=initialize_sql:add(value="DELETE from public.jgroupsping WHERE cluster_name = '${jgroups.tcp.cluster_name}'; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.jgroupsping (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,)ping_data bytea NULL, ip varchar(100) NOT NULL,)node_name varchar(100) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT jgroupsping_pkey PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));")`

Comment: I was thinking that maybe when I pass for example` \$\{some.property.value\}` to jboss it will not be resolved and then jboss will automatically use raw value without escape characters, like this: `${some.property.value}`. But there is no such escape character. You can escape expression like this and it won't be evaluated, but then jboss will use `\$\{some.property.value\}` as property value. My solution was to put escaped property value in custom-handler definition, and then intercept it in code and manually convert it using regex from `\$\{some.property.value\}`  to `${some.property.value}`.

Comment: So you can escape expression like this to prevent resolving by jboss, but then you have to manually parse it in your application code.

Comment: Thanks, my error was due to the simple fact that jgroups.tcp.cluster_name was not valued anywhere. I set it like system-property and the execution go straight.